# Grease Pencil - 2D Animation - Curve Editing control not available / visible

Tags: edit-mode, grease-pencil, 2d

I'm using Blender 2.91.2. The *Curve Editing* control is not displayed in *2D Animation* view in *Edit Mode*. What do I have to do for the control to appear?